# How to make new table out of existing table in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am working on a productivity dashboard that's calculated as
for every user, like `sum(ro)/((sum(bays)*number of days))`.
The number of days that are fied for every user is 25 days.

This formula returns the productivtity.

```
Producitvity = 
 IF(SUM(ram[Bays])>0,
     IF (
        COUNTROWS(FILTER(ram, ram[Date] = DATE(2023, 3, 1))) > 0,
        (SUM(ram[RO])/12) / (SUM(ram[Bays]) * 25),
        SUM(ram[RO]) / (SUM(ram[Bays]) * 25)
         ),""
    )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFaxx.png)

In this image, there is a table containing the productivity of the current and previous months and the current month's improvement.

What I wants to do is create a new sheet that contains this table data in the same format.

Comment: Clarify your question please - you want to create a Calculated Table of that visual?